# this в unit тестах jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Как в тестах Jasmine подменить созданному объекту другой this?

```
const PageFactory = SuperClass => class extends SuperClass {
  getNumber(n) {
    this.number.curs(n);
  }
}
```

так как pageFactory передают superclass То там есть переменная number и внутри него фукнция curs, но при вызове из теста нет возможности подставить number c функцией curs,
пытался так

```
it('test', () => {
  let pageFactory = new (PageFactory(Object));
  pageFactory.number = jasmine.createSpy('curs');
  pageFactory.pageNumber(4);
});
```

и вот здесь выдает ошибку что number is undefined или если со spy то curs is undefined;

Comment: а зачем вам это понадобилось?

Comment: Код в вопросе не является синтаксически корректным.

Comment: потому что  number is undefined, Так как этот класс использует context который подставляется другой функции, но так как я сейчас вызываю из теста соответственно number Не определен

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. желание подменить **this** говорит, что вероятно вы что-то не так делаете.

Comment: @mikhail-vaysman изменил описание

Comment: О.. Снова этот код...

Comment: А что проверяет этот тест?

Answer (score 0):

> pageFactory.number = jasmine.createSpy('curs');

В зависимости от версии:

```
jasmine.createSpy('status').andReturn(n => n);
```

```
jasmine.createSpy('status').and.return(n => n);
```

Comment: Работает, но теперь хочу проверить вызывается ли данная функция, сделал так, правильно ли?
  
     it('test', () => {
          let pageFactory = new (PageFactory(Object));
          let number = () => {};
          spyOn(number, 'curs');
            pageFactory.number = number;
            expect(number.curs).toHaveBeenCalled();
          });

Comment: Помести в andReturn другой spy и проверяй его.

Comment: Не понял, ведь createSpy Только создаст но не получится его отслеживать

Comment: А для чего же тогда нужен spy?

Comment: я хочу проверить вызов curs